# How to update data in the React Lifecycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question regarding data updates in the React Lifecycle.

The NewsTable child component receives props (query) from the parent component, which then calls the database and renders a table. The parent will also send updated props (new queries) so the table can be updated. If the parent fires the same query twice, the table shouldn't update (that is, it shouldn't keep hitting the database with identical queries). For now, I would like to use shouldComponentUpdate to handle this, but eventually I will use a "debounce" library.

Here's a code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';

var NewsTable = React.createClass({displayName: "NewsTable",
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
        };
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            query: null
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.loadData(this.props.query);
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
    },

    loadData: function(query) {
        // time-consuming async, return "data"
        this.setState({
            query: query,
            data: data
        });
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(newProps, newState) {
        if (newState.query != newProps.query) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },

    componentWillUpdate: function(newProps, newState) {
        this.loadData(newProps.query);
        newState.query = newProps.query;
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function(oldProps, oldState) {
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log("NewsTable -> render");
        if (this.props.query != null) {
            return <div/>
        }
    }
});

export default NewsTable;
```

Here NewsTable is a child component that receives a "query" prop, which sends a request to the database, and then renders a table.

Specifically:

1. the incoming prop "query" is passed to NewsTable.
2. When the component is initialized, both getDefaultProps and getInitialState are launched.
3. Then the componentWillMount function is called, which fires a database request, and calls the loadData function. When the request returns from the database, it calls setState. According to the docs, here setState does not automatically call render, but render is called automatically after the componentWillMount function. Is this the correct place to load the data from the database?
4. render is then called, followed by componentDidMount. Should I put the loadData request in the componentDidMount instead, which is similar to the docs? http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html in which case, a setState in componentDidMount will call shouldComponentUpdate, and compare the query arguments.

Now what happens when the parent component changes the query prop?

In this case, the updated prop calls shouldComponentUpdate -> componentWillUpdate -> loadData -> setState() -> shouldComponentUpdate ??? It's going into an infinite loop.

How should I best update the code snippet to handle updated query props, and block repetitive calls?

Comment: Why wait until the component is updating to request new data and save the last query? In `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` you can see if the query is newer than the last saved state. If it is, `setState({ query })` then call `loadData` and set new data state when that call returns

Comment: I agree with @azium. I'd say it more directly, too: this is *built in* to React. Your component *will* update when it gets new props, though you can customize this with `shouldComponentUpdate`. Also, to answer your question, async calls like DB queries should go in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`, [per the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).